# Cannot connect to eduroam from ubuntu

Tags: wireless, connection

I am trying to connect to eduroam from Ubuntu, and it asks me for certificates. I asked my college tech support and the answer I got was "I don't know anything about Linux or Ubuntu,  all our machines are windows or macs". I asked one of the lecturers and he said that there is no certificate needed.

How can I fix it?

Comment: On the topic itself: It is likely possible to adapt the instructions for Mac and Windows to Ubuntu. I remember my university asked me to download and install a certificate, after that eduroam worked fine on my Ubuntu laptop. If you could maybe share the instructions provided to you, we might be able to adapt them more safely to Ubuntu than disabling cert checking and hard-coding clear-text passwords…

Comment: @amon yes I will answer the question in 17 hours as it suggests, thanks. As for the instructions, they gave me none just what I stated above that is why I asked in here. Our tech department only helps if its windows and even at that the help can cause more problems.

Comment: [Here is a guide](http://wiki.cs.huji.ac.il/wiki/Wireless/eduroam) where detailed connection instructions for linux users are provided. In particular, it gives all the information on how to configure eduroam both via GUI and command line, and where to find the CA certificate under linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's the correct way but it works fine for me.

Open the configuration file which can be found at `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

Open terminal and use command

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam
```

Look for and remove

```
system-ca-cert=true
```

and change

```
password-flags=1
```

to

```
password=YourPassword
```

Comment: It is better not to store password as text. Instead, leave `password` empty, which you can enter when prompted.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and I followed [Gman's fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/573398/527764), which almost worked for me.

In my case the client automatically edited a '-' into the middle of my username.

```
identity = user-name@student.university.com
```

I removed the '-' and was good to go.