# Erratic connectivity problems with Eduroam on 14.04 - possible workarounds?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I have to connect to eduroam through TU Delft settings from the following link

https://intranet.tudelft.nl/fileadmin/Files/medewerkersportal/ict/Help/Handleidingen/Medewerkers/Draadloos_netwerk/Eduroam/doc/Linux-wireless_eduroam1.0-EN.pdf

The connection problem is not one but many - sometimes I cannot connect to the wifi itself, most of the times I get connected but get no internet access, but magically in one of the buildings I was able to run everything like a charm.

The problem is that I can connect to most other wifi networks and on my windows boot everything is a charm.

Can anyone suggest any workarounds/ mends for this issue ?

EDIT: here's the status when the system was connected to the network:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"eduroam"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:26:CB:42:90:80   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: c0:cb:38:95:07:56
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) ip=145.136.78.200 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:17 memory:fbd00000-fbd03fff
```

Comment: more detail would be helpful. I'm afraid I don't have enough information to work with here. I would surmise that the answer could be found in `man iwconfig` if we had a full understanding of the problem. This is a great place to start: http://askubuntu.com/questions/236119/how-do-i-troubleshoot-problems-with-my-wireless-connection

Comment: Any feed-back on above comment???

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/573398/455406) for a password setting in the connection config file.

Advice is different at each organisation:
[Hebrew Uni Jerusalem](http://wiki.cs.huji.ac.il/wiki/Wireless/eduroam) - bonus for including commandline instructions ;